# Return for type void function

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, void

I'm trying to program a function that allows me to locate a substring "from" in a string "src", and replace the "from" substring with the "to" substring in all cases, and output the new string through "dest"; however I think my code looks a bit iffy, and I do not understand (conceptually) how I would return an output with dest, given that the output is of type void. I was wondering if someone could offer some assistance?

for example:

```
find_replace("pooppoop poop", "poo", "hel", dest) should return

"helphelp help"
```

thank you!

```
void find_replace(char* src, char* from, char* to, char* dest)
{
  dest = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(src)+sizeof(from));
  int i;
  int j;
  int check = 1;
  for (i = 0; i <= strlen(src) - 1; i++) {
    if (src[i] == from[0]) {
      for (j = 0; j <= strlen(from) - 1; i++) {
        if (src[i+j] != from[j]) {
          check = 0;}
        else {
          continue;
        }}}
    if (check == 1) {
      char * str3 = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(&src[i]) + strlen(to));
      strcpy(str3, &src[i]);
      strcat(str3, to);
    }
    else { continue; }
  }
  return ;
```

Comment: I can't follow the logic of your function, can you explain it? what is str3?

Comment: So I guess I'm pretty new at coding, but the idea was to create a character array of length "src" (up to the point i, where it matches with from) and the length of "to". I then wanted to copy src[i] onto str3 that I had created, and strcat str3 and to in order to create the new string that had both of them.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate memory for a new string in your example, but the calling code cannot acces this variable.

Basically, there are three methods to pass a string. Each has advantages and drawbacks.

- **Pass a fixed-size buffer**

  ```
  int repl1(char *dest, int n, const char *src, const char *find, const char *repl)
  ```

  Here, the calling function provides a buffer to which the function can write. It is a good idea to provide a maximum buffer length, so that the function does not overflow that buffer. The arguments, whose contents you don't intend to change should be `const`, i.e. pointers to unmodifiable data.

  Such a function can be `void`, but it could also return an integer that indicates how long the string in `dest` is.

  The advantage is that you can easily pass automatic buffers. The disadvantage ist that these buffers might be too small for the task.

  Call the function like this:

  ```
  char buf[80];
  int n = repl1(buf, sizeof(buf), str, "this", "that");
  ```
- **Return allocated memory**

  ```
  char *repl2(const char *src, const char *find, const char *repl)
  ```

  Here, the function should allocate new memory to hold the buffer. The function returns the pointer to the new memory. That memory "belongs" to the calling function, which then is responsible for freeing the memory.

  The advantage is that the function can allocate enough memory for the task. The disadvantage is that the calling function must take care of managing the new memory.

  Call the function like this:

  ```
  char *dest = repl2(str, "this", "that");

  // Do stuff whith 'dest' ...
  free(dest);
  ```
- **Pass a pointer to a poiner to char**

  ```
  int repl3(char **dest, const char *src, const char *find, const char *repl)
  ```

  This is a variant of returning the pointer, where the pointer is passed by reference and can therefore be changed. The function also has access to the old contents to the `dest` char buffer. That is not useful in your case. I have only mentioned this possibility for completeness.

  Call the function like this:

  ```
  char *buf;
  int n = repl3(&buf, str, "this", "that");
  ```

This answer addresses the ways of passing data. Your code uses the second method, so you should return `dest`, but not pass it in as parameter. I have not looked at your function logic.

Answer (score 0):

Void type method won't return anything, what you can do is change the type of your function to string and return a string.

Answer (score 0):

[Apart from analyzing the logic of your function] A function with a return type `void` won't [and can't] *return* any value using the `return` statement. Also, worthy to mention, you cannot *return* more than one *value* [as you need] using a `return` statement, either.

To get the *return* value(s) in your case, you're supposed to call your function and pass pointer(s) to `char` as argument. Then, inside your function, when you *assign/alter* values of the locations pointed by those pointers, they will get modified and after returning from your function, in the caller function, you'll have the modified value.

This is another way to have more than one *return* value at a time from a called function.

Comment: is there any way you (or anyone else) could help me through my logic as well?

Comment: @LeehoLim you should read about `strstr()` function and how strings work in c.

Answer (score 0):

Void means nothing, so you can't return a value with a void function. 
I assume you want to use call-by-reference instead of call-by-value, if you want to use a void function.
This means, that you give a pointer to the function, to tell where your array is located. Then you work with your 'real' array, instead of a copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
 printf("%s\n",find_replace("pooppoop poop", "poo", "hel", dest));

char * find_replace(char* src, char* from, char* to, char* dest)
 {
   dest = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(src)+sizeof(from));
   int i;
   int j;
   int check = 1;
   for (i = 0; i <= strlen(src) - 1; i++) {
     if (src[i] == from[0]) {
       for (j = 0; j <= strlen(from) - 1; i++) {
         if (src[i+j] != from[j]) {
           check = 0;}
         else {
           continue;
     }}}
     if (check == 1) {
        char * str3 = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(&src[i]) + strlen(to));
        strcpy(str3, &src[i]);
        strcat(str3, to);
        return str3 ;
     }
    else { continue; }
  }
 return "";
}
```

Comment: `return strcat `...what is that, please?

Comment: no , its depends on programmer what he wants to print if no match found.

Comment: Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` – it adds no value but it decreases readability and can hide errors.

Comment: @pankajkhanduja-GameChanger how can `C` syntax depend on programmer? :-) BTW, i was referring to `return str3 ` which lacks `;`

Comment: @sourav Thanks . Actually i was talking about this - return "";

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
dest = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(src)+sizeof(from));
```

overrides the address passed in

```
void find_replace(char* src, char* from, char* to, char* dest)
```

If you want to allocate memory *inside* the function (which I think you have to, because the caller *cannot* know how much to reserve), you have to tell the caller where the result data ends up in. Either you opt for an out-parameter:

```
void find_replace(char* src, char* from, char* to, char** dest)
{
  *dest = malloc(...);
```

*or*, what I would prefer, you return the pointer:

```
char* find_replace(char* src, char* from, char* to)
{
  char* dest = malloc(...);
  // ...
  return dest;
}
```